# TabbedForm not highlighting which tab has an error

Tags: react-admin

I have a `TabbedForm` with 2 tabs, each tab having a single `required()` field. When I submit this form and the validation fails, I expect the unfocussed tab(s) to indicate that there is an error with a field within the tab (e.g. with a red underline or red text).

This appears to be working fine in a react-admin demo (https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/products/126) however even after looking a the source code for this example (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/products/ProductEdit.tsx), I cannot seem to replicate the same functionality in my project.

I have the following code:

```
const App = () => {
  const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
  );

  return (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
      <Resource name="users" list={ListGuesser} edit={EditForm} />
    </Admin>
  );
};
```

```
export const EditForm = (props: EditProps) => {
  return (
    <Edit {...props}>
      <TabbedForm>
        <FormTab label="Tab 1">
          <TextInput source="name" validate={required()} />
        </FormTab>
        <FormTab label="Tab 2">
          <TextInput source="username" validate={required()} />
        </FormTab>
      </TabbedForm>
    </Edit>
  );
};
```

[Image showing Tab 2 selected and is valid and there is a validation error on Tab 1, but no highlight on Tab 1 to tell the user that this is the Tab that has the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DELY5.png)

There has been a similar question asked here ([Show Tab Form Validation For Inputs Not Direct Children Of <FormTab>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135210/show-tab-form-validation-for-inputs-not-direct-children-of-formtab/)) but the resolution does not apply to my problem.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

plz check the demo source code: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/products/ProductEdit.tsx, it's using validate function:

```
<RichTextInput source="description" label="" validate={req} />
```

and the "req" is defined at line 86:

```
const req = [required()];
```

I've encountered same problem, and solve it by using the way (validation function) of demo source code. HTH

Answer (score 0):

TextInput requires `validate={required()}` to invoke the framework's error message. Only `required` calls the browser's field validation.